# Div Vertically aligning an image

Tags: html, css

I have a div with image "image.jpg".

By using `text-align=center`, the image is being centered horizontally.

However it's not vertically aligned. How would I implement the vertical alignment?

```
<div style="vertical-align: middle;text-align:center;">
    <img title="Title3" src="image.jpg" style="display: inline;" id="idImage">
</div>
```

Comment: Neither a bad question nor poor. So did not deserve down-vote :)

Comment: @SamiAkram as to the research effort, this question is clearly lacking. a simple google search: 'vertical align' discovers this page as link 2. http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the height of the parent container and set your `margin-top: auto`, it should align to the middle I think. This works with horizontally aligning, but I haven't tried with vertical. Anyways, it would avoid absolute positioning

As mentioned before, you can also use javascript to find the height, then set the margin, something like this:

```
var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
var imgHeight = image.style.height;
image.style.marginTop = -(imgHeight/2);
image.style.top = 50%; //you can probably just set this in css and omit this line
```

you must of course set

```
#myImage{
  position: absolute;
}
```

though

Answer (score 1):

Use the `vertical-align` property as described in [this article](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html). Note that in order to get `vertical-align` to work you need to do `display: table-cell` as well.

```
div.centered {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    /* other styling */
}
```

Where I've given your `<div>` the class name of `centered`.

Also you shouldn't use `text-align` for centering, but instead add `margin: 0 auto;` to the image styling.

**EDIT**

HTML:

```
<div class="centered">
    <img src="..." class="centered-image" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.centered {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img.centered-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: dnt get it , how my code will change.
please change my code in question for clear explanation

Comment: @chicharito What don't you understand? Put a class called "centered" on your div -- `<div class="centered">` -- and then put the above CSS in your style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the dimensions for this to work (or use javascript to get the dimensions if you'll have different ones). This will also center the image horizontally (so you don't need your `text-align=center` )

Taken from [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/)

```
.center {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -150px;
   margin-top: -150px;
}
```

height and width are that of the image in question and the top and left margins are set at half the respective height and width.

Comment: i dont know the image height and width.then is there any solution

Comment: if you don't know, then you could guestimate and play around with it until it looks centered enough to you, try something like `top: 40%` and go from there

Comment: unless the image is changed frequently though, you can right click (in google chrome) and hit inspect element to find the dimensions of the image

Comment: image will be random and hence the dimensions